# How does the Unity Game-engine deal with the computational time needed beeing larger than the fixed update time step?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In a Unity C# project, to use FixedUpdate(), I am using a time step: Time.fixedDeltaTime, that is equal to 0.002. Now I checked the real time that takes place between two FixedUpdate() iterations, this value varies, but is around 2-3 times larger than the fixedDeltaTime.
Therefore I am wondering, what influence this will have on my project.
As far as I understood the fixedDeltaTime, then the actual timestep used will still be the same, but as Unity runs in real time, I am wondering, if the project then just does not run synchronously (so that the time of the physics calculations of the project are behind the real time?).
I also tried to make the time step even smaller, but then the project just does not run (although the fixed updates are called, nothing moves/ behaves as expected)
Here the difference between the actual time the project needed to calculate the dynamics and the fixedTimestep were even larger (4+ times as large).

The second point I am worried about is, if Unity instead of the physics simulation beeing behind the rendered real time: might change the FixedDeltaTime?

I have found something about the last question here: https://discussions.unity.com/t/how-to-make-physics-truly-update-in-real-time/244797
But I am not sure, how to test if this is also the case/ relevant in my project.

I am wondering, how to find out:

1. if the fixedTimeStep changes? (if I just debug.log the variable, then it returns the wanted time step, but I am not sure, if this is correct/ or only the wrong way to output its value.
2. what changes when the FixedDeltaTime is continuously smaller than the time needed to calculate the implemented physics
3. what happens when the time step is much smaller than the time needed to calculate the implemented physics (as explained above, in my project, it lead to the dynamics not starting, so I am wondering, what reasons for this might be) (so why it still seems to work for smaller differences between the fixedtimestep and the time actually needed to run the update and larger differences). So therefore I am wondering, what system this is based on, that it "suddenly" seems to stop working.

Thank you very much for all help & best regards

Answer (score 0):

Never play with the time step unless you know what you're doing and have a real need to do so. `Update` and `FixedUpdate` rely on the users hardware so there can be huge differences between one users frame rate and anothers.

`Update` runs as fast as possible at any given loop; depending on what's going on in the game, with the users device and many other factors the speed will vary.

`FixedUpdate` as the name suggests always runs at a constant rate regardless of what's going on; however you have no realistic control over that constant frequency as the game will be deployed to many different devices with different specs.

> The second point I am worried about is, if Unity instead of the
> physics simulation beeing behind the rendered real time: might change
> the FixedDeltaTime?

Never.

- Q1: No.
- Q2: The laws of physics go out the window and the universe
  explodes. Don't do it! Being serious though the physics simly won't calculate that frame. Given it's a constant rate and you set a value lower than the users machine can process they will never get a physics update.
- Q3: It never will be. If you're having issues
  with physics the problem will be elsewhere. Post a fresh question explaining the issue.